# How do I get the bootstrap modal to work in my code?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

Hey there I am just have trouble bringing up a modal working with bootstrap. Theoretically I have a list of pokemon that I fetched from another website. Then each pokemon is supposed to act as a button to where i can then click on and receive more information about. I would appreciate some help as I am pretty lost.
Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Simple JS App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <header class="page-header">
          <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <h1>Pokedex</h1>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
    
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group"></ul>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    
    JS
    let pokemonRepository = (function () {
      let pokemonList = [];
      let apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150';
    
      function add(pokemon) {
        pokemonList.push(pokemon);
      }
    
      function getAll() {
        return pokemonList;
      }
      function addListItem(pokemon) {
        let pokemonList = document.querySelector('.list-group');
        let listPokemon = document.createElement('li');
        listPokemon.classList.add('group-list-item');
        let button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = pokemon.name;
        button.classList.add('btn');
        pokemonList.appendChild(listPokemon);
        listPokemon.appendChild(button);
        button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          showDetails(pokemon);
        });
      }
    
      function loadList() {
        return fetch(apiUrl).then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function (json) {
          json.results.forEach(function (item) {
            let pokemon = {
              name: item.name,
              detailsUrl: item.url
            };
            add(pokemon);
            console.log(pokemon);
          });
        }).catch(function (e) {
          console.error(e);
        });
      }
    
      function loadDetails(item) {
        let url = item.detailsUrl;
        return fetch(url).then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function (details) {
          // Now we add the details to the item
          item.imageUrl = details.sprites.front_default;
          item.height = details.height;
          item.types = details.types;
        }).catch(function (e) {
          console.error(e);
        });
      }
    
      function showDetails(pokemon) {
        loadDetails(pokemon).then(function () {
          showModal(pokemon);
        });
      };
    
      function showModal(item) {
        let modalContainer = document.querySelector('#myModal');
        modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
        // Clear all existing modal content
        modalContainer.innerHTML = '';
        modalContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          // Since this is also triggered when clicking INSIDE the modal
          // We only want to close if the user clicks directly on the overlay
          let target = e.target;
          if (target === modalContainer) {
            hideModal();
          }
        });
    
        let modal = document.createElement('div');
        modal.classList.add('modal');
    
        // Add the new modal content
        let closeButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
        closeButtonElement.classList.add('modal-close');
        closeButtonElement.innerText = 'Close';
        closeButtonElement.addEventListener('click', hideModal);
    
        let titleElement = document.createElement('h1');
        titleElement.innerText = item.name + (':    ') + ('height =  ') + item.height;
    
        let container = document.querySelector('#image-container');
        let myImage = document.createElement('img');
        myImage.src = item.imageUrl;
    
        modal.appendChild(closeButtonElement);
        modal.appendChild(titleElement);
        modalContainer.appendChild(modal);
        modal.appendChild(myImage);
      }
    
      function hideModal() {
        let modalContainer = document.querySelector('#myModal');
        modalContainer.classList.remove('is-visible');
      }
    
      window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        let modalContainer = document.querySelector('#myModal');
        if (e.key === 'Escape' && modalContainer.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
          hideModal();
        }
      });
    
      return {
        add: add,
        getAll: getAll,
        addListItem: addListItem,
        loadList: loadList,
        loadDetails: loadDetails,
        showDetails: showDetails
      };
    })();
    
    
    
    pokemonRepository.loadList().then(function () {
      pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function (pokemon) {
        pokemonRepository.addListItem(pokemon);
      });
    });
```

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - There is few errors in your code. To open a bootstrap modal there is a method:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

2 - Then you cleaned the structure of the modal with the innerHTML instead of the modal-body and you are trying to recreate all the elements dynamically.

What you can do is just replacing the content of the modal body or do not forget to re-create **every element** of the modal which is not what you did.

Here is a working example:

https://codepen.io/alxtaz/pen/WNXYOrd

Comment: Thanks this helped alot!! It was really nice to see the codepen example. I could really look through everything slowly and see how it was working. 

But how do I change the styles of the buttons? like color and spacing?

Comment: The modal buttons ?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. Not the modal buttons but the buttons of pokemon that are in the list-group div. For example I know without bootstrap i would just go to css and apply attributes to the div classes. But with bootstrap I am not so sure where to do that.

Comment: Using regular css or Bootstrap is quite the same, just add the css class you want. For example in your addListItem function ,update the button like this: button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary', 'my-1');